# In Org-Mode, is there a way to narrow the buffer to just the text under a heading?

Tags: org-mode

For example, say I have a buffer that looks like this:

```
* Org-Mode

This is a document written in Org-Mode

** This is a subheading below that
```

Would it be possible to narrow the buffer to just "This is a document written in Org-Mode" and continue on then come back to the full buffer, excluding the subheading below.

(Edited to clarify regarding subheadings)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want Org-mode to work somewhat like the Workflowy app ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps this does what you want?

```
(defun org-narrow-to-here ()
   (interactive)
   (org-narrow-to-subtree)
   (save-excursion
     (org-next-visible-heading 1)
     (narrow-to-region (point-min) (point))))
```

**Edit:** If you really really want to exclude the current heading, this more elaborate variant:

```
(defun org-narrow-to-here ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (narrow-to-region
     (progn (unless (org-at-heading-p) (org-next-visible-heading -1))
            (forward-line)
            (point))
     (progn (org-next-visible-heading 1)
            (point)))))
```

Comment: To make it more robust, consider adding code to the start of the second `progn` to throw an error if `(org-at-heading-p)` is true. In this case, there is no text to narrow to between the two headings.

Answer (score 25):

`org-narrow-to-subtree` (C-x n s) will display only the current heading. It does however include the heading itself, not *just* the text. Maybe that is OK for you?

`widen` (C-x n w) will widen the view again.

See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156595/in-emacs-org-mode-how-to-narrow-display-to-two-subtrees-in-two-separate-files

Comment: Not exactly. The problem with that approach is that if there are subheadings below that text, they're included in the narrowed in the buffer as well. Thank you, though.

Comment: Ah OK - maybe you could clarify in your question that you specifically want to exclude subheadings below the given heading

Comment: also this has the problem that the indentation stays the same :( does not help on phones where there is little space...